# implement DAO in spring boot with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entity, dao

I am writing query using In operator in spring boot using JPA

*`select * from data where name in ("XYZ","XY")`*

I am unable to implement DAO implementation for the following input in spring boot with JPA.

```
 {"name":["XYZ","XY"]}
```

#### Controller

```java
@PostMapping("/embdata/dto/name")
public List getByBatchIdsWithDTO(@RequestBody EmbDataDTO dto){
    return service.getBatchIds(dto);
}
```

#### Service Method:

```java
    List<Data> obj=repo.findBybatchID(List<String> name)
```

#### Repo Interface:

```java
    List<Data> findByBatchIdIn(List wageId);
```

#### My entity Class

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="data")
public class Data{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="address")
    String address;
}
```

#### My DTO class:

```
@Data
public class EmbDataDTO {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String address;
}
```

please help me to implement for the following input.

Comment: Do you get an exception or what is the result of repo.findBybatchID?

Comment: getting result but it says unable to convert entity class to DTO class.

Comment: Where is this error? Can you please post the stacktrace? And your repo implementatoin?

Comment: Why you don't implement a mapper for converting entity to dto? Or just use BeanUtils :)

Comment: I feel like there are lot missing in the question, can you just feed enough details like `exception`, `the proper request body`,  `JpaRepository interface`

Answer (score 0):

Your repo should look like :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
class YourRepo {
  List<Data> findByBatchIdIn(List wageId) {
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select * from data where name in (:list)");
    q.setListParameter("list", wageId); 
    return q.execute(); 
  }
}
```

At least something like that.